# Is the ember cli addon installation broken in Ember Cli 0.1.11?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, add-on

I'm using ember cli for some small test projects to evaluate the concepts. Normal use of ember cli works for me. After 10 created small projects and using blueprints and the pod structure I decided to try the development and usage of addons. The creation of addons was not the real problem.

The problem is I can not successfully install a created addon. I also tried to install other addons created by other ember-cli users. The result is always the same. I got no error message and the addon could be found inside the node_modules directory of the addon consuming application but there is nothing installed in the app directory and it's sub directories !!!

What can I do to find the problem ? 
Do you have a public available addon which could be installed definitely without problems ?

Are there log files which could be inspected to see more details (hidden error messages) ?

Best regads

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

The current Ember CLI version is `0.0.12`. I'm not aware of any issues with addon installations. If the issue persist, you should create an issue on [ember-cli issue tracker](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues).